# Unity, C#, SocketIO: variables, objects, methods not accessible in callback/action

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, socket.io

As the title suggests, I am not able to access some variables/objects and their methods in a callback action for socker.io.
Here is my code to illustrate the problem:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using SocketIOClient;

public class SimulationManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject robot;
    private MovementController movement;
    private SensorController sensors;

    [Header("Setup")]
    [SerializeField] private string serverIP;
    [SerializeField] private string serverPort;

    private SocketIO socket;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        movement = robot.GetComponent<MovementController>();
        sensors = robot.GetComponent<SensorController>();

        InitSockets();
    }

    private void InitSockets()
    {
        string address = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", serverIP, serverPort);
        socket = new SocketIO(address);

        // standard connection and error events
        socket.OnConnected += (sender, e) => {
            Debug.Log("socket connected");

            // register to server as simulation
            socket.EmitAsync("register", "simulation");
        };

        socket.OnDisconnected += (sender, e) => Debug.Log("socket disconnected");
        socket.OnError += (sender, e) => Debug.Log("socket error: " + e);
        
        // handle receiving commands
        Action<SocketIOResponse> callback = OnCommandReceived;
        socket.On("command", callback);

        socket.ConnectAsync();
    }

    private void OnCommandReceived(SocketIOResponse command)
    {
        string type = command.GetValue<string>(0);
        float parameter = float.Parse(command.GetValue<string>(1));

        Debug.Log(string.Format("command received: {0} {1}", type, parameter));
        movement.Rotate(90f);
    }

}
```

In `OnCommandReceived` I am trying access the previously declared movement-object and call it's method `Rotate(...)`. The object does not appear to be null, because it does not show any errors in the unity console when trying to access it and it also does not crash the game. The `Debug.Log(...)`, that outputs the received command works just fine. Declaring a string as a property of my class and outputting it that way is possible aswell. Just as soon as I introduce the movement or sensors objects to `Debug.Log(...)` it never shows up in the console and, as I said before, bizzarly without any error whatsoever.

Accessing the desired variables/methods/properties is not problematic coming from within other contexts in the class.

Also I did not forget to set the reference to the robot-object inside the unity editor, so don't worry about that. That would also at least give me an error message in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue now. The problem was that

1. The SocketIO library caught all occuring exceptions, but did not put anything out in the console. I just had to surround my method call in a try-catch to see what went wrong.
   and
2. unity is not thread safe and so you cannot call methods from any thread other than the main one.

More details on how to solve this issue can be found [in a reddit post here](https://redd.it/reubd9).